# Is $\frac{10}{459}$ a cube in $\Bbb{Q}_3$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

Is $\frac{10}{459}$ a cube in $\Bbb{Q}_3$, the 3-adic numbers?

My general strategy for showing if something is a cube in $\Bbb{Q}_3$ has been:

- Use Hensel's Lemma to show it is (1)
- If it isn't, suppose for contradiction it is a cube and equate 3-adic valuations to see if we can find a contradiction (2)
- If it isn't, suppose for contradiction it is a cube and reduce modulo $3^k$ for some $k$ and try to arrive at a contradiction. (3)

(2) doesn't help in this instance, and I don't think I can apply either (1) or (3) as the number in question is a fraction.

How can I attempt to answer the question: "Is $x$ a cube in $\Bbb{Q}_3$?" in this specific case, when $x = \frac{10}{459}$, and I'm also interested in a general strategy for when $x$ is a fraction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First determine the valuation of the fraction by getting it for the numerator and denominator:

$v(10)=0, v(459)=v(17×27)=3, v(10/459)=v(10)-v(459)=-3=\text{a multiple of 3}$

Then since $v(10/459)$ is a multiple of $3$, we will have a cube if the integer obtained by shifting the "decimal point" so that the last nonzero digit is at the units place is a cube.  Multiply your fraction by $3^3=27$ to make this adjustment, setting $v$ to zero:

$(10/459)×3^3=10/17$

The resulting fraction will be a 3-adic cube, completing our test, if its residue $\bmod 9$ is $\pm1$.  Here $10\equiv1$ and $17\equiv-1$, so $(10/17)\equiv-1$ making it a $3$-adic cube, and then $(10/17)×(1/3^3)=10/459$ will be one also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I don't quite follow. My understanding of the 3-adic valuation (is this what your $v$ stands for?) is that $\vert{\frac{10}{459}}\vert_3 = 27$, not $-3$. I also don't follow the sentence "we will have a cube if the terminal nonzero digits correspond to one". Would you mind elaborating? Thank you!

Comment: The cube root to seven figures is ...101212.2.

Comment: In Oscar’s answer, “valuation” means the *additive* valuation, not the absolute value. It measures the divisibility by $3$, and is additive in the sense that $v(ab)=v(a)+v(b)$. You might think of $v(a)$ as $-\log_3(|a|_3)$.